# How do I completely purge ALL kontact and akonadi configuration?

Tags: kubuntu, email, imap, kmail, kontact

I have a very specific problem with Kmail. I cannot login to one of my imap mail accounts. 3x other imap mail accounts are working perfectly but not that one. I first thought it might be the mail account, but when I tried it on a fresh Kubuntu vm installation it worked also with that mail account.

So I thought it's most likely because of some wrong configuration. Unfortunately I didn't find a way to completely purge my Kmail, Kontact and Akonadi configuration and databases. All my attempts failed so far.

I have already tried the following:

1. removing:

`rm -r ~/.config/akonadi*`

`rm -r ~/.local/share/akonadi*`

`apt purge --auto-remove akonadi-server`

2. stopping some services with:

`akonadiconsole`

I tried to remove some of the services (like "local folders"). This didn't help either.

When I start "Kontact -> Kmail -> Settings -> Configure KMail" I still see the old Identities. So I guess not all the data (configuration or database) is removed. How do I **completely remove all the configuration and databases** and do a fresh Kontact reinstallation.

All in all my system is working quite well so I would like to avoid a complete Kubuntu reinstallation.

Thank you for your help. :)